# How to access Sonata admin pool in form type

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

### Use case

I' m trying to reuse sonata_type_model_list in the front admin of my website by defining this in my buildForm method of my Entity FormType :

```
[...]
->add('position', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
      'model_manager' => $categoryManager,
))
[...]
```

However I can't use

```
$categoryAdmin = $this
    ->getConfigurationPool()
    ->getAdminByClass("\\Application\\Sonata\\ClassificationBundle\\Entity\\Category");
```

As I need to be in an AdminClass to use `getConfigurationPool()`.

If anyone knows how to use `getConfigurationPool()` outside of an AdminClass or do you know how to declare `sonata_type_model_list` in order to use it outside of an admin class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

Thanks to [@pbenard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2454790/pbenard) & [@Mawcel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5758328/mawcel) for their answers, I combined them to achieve my goal as follow:

---

**In my controller** I create my form and inject `$this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool')` to it like so :

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    new FormType($this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool')), 
    $entity, 
    $options
);
```

**In my formType**, I added the property $adminPool && the __construct method:

```
private $adminPool;

public function __construct(Pool $adminPool) {
    $this->adminPool = $adminPool;
}
```

So **I can now access the adminPool** from the buildForm method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    [...]
    $categoryAdmin = $this
        ->getConfigurationPool()
        ->getAdminByClass("\\Application\\Sonata\\ClassificationBundle\\Entity\\Category"        );
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the admin pool in your form type.

Here is an example:

```
#services.yml

blast_base_entities.form.type.my:
        class: Blast\BaseEntitiesBundle\Form\Type\MyformType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: blast_search_index_autocomplete }
        arguments: [@sonata.admin.pool]
```

And in the form type:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool

Class MyFormType
{
    private $adminPool;

    public function construct(Pool $adminPool)
    {
        $this->adminPool = $adminPool;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve admins

`$this->adminPool->getAdminByClass('Foo')`;

Answer (score 0):

As writing in [the doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html#managing-admin-service), maybe you can use the `sonata.admin.pool` service.

```
$configurationPool = $this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool');
```

Comment: I'm not creating an Admin as SonataAdmin does, I'm converting a regular front page as an "front admin". I'm using a CRUD generated by app/console and I use the FormType provided. Within the FormType `$this->container` is not accessible as it doesn't exists.

Comment: the problem is within the FormType `$this->container` is not accessible.

Comment: of course, it's an exemple, you juste have to send it via service or....